# How to trigger a keyboard "keydown" event after clicking a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mouseevent, keyboard-events, dom-events

I want to trigger a keyboard event (keydown up/down arrows) after  clicking a button in a Vue.js project.

I've tried to use `dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { keyCode: 38/40 }))` for up and down arrow keys.

```html
<template>
...
<div class="position-relative input-field__wrapper">
    <input
        class="input-field__input"
        ref="numberInput"
        type="number"
        :name="name"
        :id="randomId || id"
        :value="value"
        :min="min"
        :max="max"
        :step="step"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(disabled)"
        @input="$emit('input', e)"
        @change="$emit('change', e)"
    />
    <button
        aria-label="increment"
        class="increment position-absolute h-50"
        :disabled="incrementDisabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(incrementDisabled)"
        @click="increment"
    ></button>
    <button
        aria-label="decrement"
        class="decrement position-absolute h-50"
        :disabled="decrementDisabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(decrementDisabled)"
        @click="decrement"
    ></button>
</div>
...
</template>
```

```
<script>
...
methods: {
    increment() {
        this.$el
            .getElementsByClassName("increment")[0]
            .dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { keyCode: 38 }));
    },
    decrement() {
        this.$el
            .getElementsByClassName("decrement")[0]
            .dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent("keydown", { keyCode: 40 }));
    },
}
...
</script>
```

I just do not want to add so many methods, just want my buttons act like keyboard up and down on number input.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your parent component is handling the keyup, and keydown events. Here's how you can do it.

```html
<template>
...
<div class="position-relative input-field__wrapper">
    <input
        class="input-field__input"
        ref="numberInput"
        type="number"
        :name="name"
        :id="randomId || id"
        :value="value"
        :min="min"
        :max="max"
        :step="step"
        :disabled="disabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(disabled)"
        @input="$emit('input', e)"
        @change="$emit('change', e)"
    />
    <button
        aria-label="increment"
        class="increment position-absolute h-50"
        :disabled="incrementDisabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(incrementDisabled)"
        @click="$emit('keydown', { keyCode: 38 })"
    ></button>
    <button
        aria-label="decrement"
        class="decrement position-absolute h-50"
        :disabled="decrementDisabled"
        :aria-disabled="toString(decrementDisabled)"
        @click="$emit('keydown', { keyCode: 40 })"
    ></button>
</div>
...
</template>
```

If you want the original event with the key code, you could do something like

```
@click=e => $emit('keydown', { ...e, keyCode: 38 })
```